# Rails: A method not defined by "def"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't find the definition of a method called `on_init` in the source code of a Rails application. There are no matches for `def  on_init` in the entire source code.

Does anyone knows how I can find the place the method is defined?

Comment: `def ...` it is not only one way of the method definition.

Comment: @Зелёный
Do you have any suggestions on how can I find the definition of the method? There is no hyperlink to the method definition on RubyMine neither

Comment: @blu: Try `puts Foo.class_eval{method(:on_init)}` and `puts Foo.class_eval{method(:on_init).source_location}`

Comment: Are you sure that there is such a method? Remember: there doesn't have to be a method for all messages.

Comment: Usually, people would define it as `def on_init`. I think it is rare to be defined as `def  on_init`.

Answer (score 0):

```
blu = some_object # that responds to #on_init
blu.method(:on_init).source_location
```

Comment: There is class "Foo", which has a line "on_init :bar".
I tryed:
`obj = Foo.new
obj.method(:on_init).source_location`
But it yields an error:
`'undefined method 'on_init' for class `Foo'`